# Running php script when using wordpress and openshift

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

I am a beginner in openshift and wordpress. I am trying to import joomla's articles to wordpress using this (http://www.onestopjoomla.com/extensions/migrate/joomla-to-wordpress-import-wizard/) tool. I have copied scripts to a desired directory on openeshift server. But I can't rut it.

It look's like wordpress doesn't allow to call the script and catches the request. It says that it doesn't exist. Does anyone how to deal with this problem? I can give more info if required..

Thanks in advance
Radek

Comment: I think that tool is not working as I'm reading the comments on it...

Comment: Thanks for a response. But theoretically... If I need to upload php script like helloworld.php, where should I put it to be able to run it? Has openshift instance with wordpress some public directory?

Answer (score 0):

The directory I was looking for is ~home_dir/app-root/repo/php. Now it is all about setting .htaccess file. Thanks again for the reply.